# Domain switcher button for different languages

Tags: if-statement, menu

I want to create a dropdown menu With English or German as the options in Javascript / jQuery that checks that:

```
check if on a domain  - say happy.com/pizza 
if german is selected on dropdown 
redirect user to 
happy.de/pizza
```

and I could have a list

```
if happy.com/pizza got to happy.de/pizza  
happy.com/coke got to happy.de/coke  
happy.com/juice got to happy.de/juice
```

etc etc.

I have written the code yet but how would one go about this?

Thanks!

I have written some code but I just need a little help please:

In this scenario I am on the www.something.com/beer page and want it to go to the German Beer Page!

```
<select>
    <option value="1">English</option>
    <option value="2">German</option>
</select>


if(value == 2)  && is current domain www.something.com/beer{
    window.top.location.href = 'www.something.de/beer'; 
}else if(value == 2)  && is current domain www.something.com/cheese{
    window.top.location.href = 'www.something.de/cheese'; 
}else{
    do nothing
}
```

How do I get this to check the value of the dropdown and the domain is currently on?

Here is my Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/msasz2an/

Thanks again!

Comment: Consider writing some code first and sharing that afterwards to point out the actual question.

Comment: I am doing that now :) Just wanted maybe a point the right direction if possible?

Comment: Have a look so far: http://jsfiddle.net/msasz2an/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function current(arr) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/current/
  // original by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //        note: Uses global: php_js to store the array pointer
  //   example 1: transport = ['foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane'];
  //   example 1: current(transport);
  //   returns 1: 'foot'

  this.php_js = this.php_js || {};
  this.php_js.pointers = this.php_js.pointers || [];
  var indexOf = function (value) {
    for (var i = 0, length = this.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (this[i] === value) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };
  // END REDUNDANT
  var pointers = this.php_js.pointers;
  if (!pointers.indexOf) {
    pointers.indexOf = indexOf;
  }
  if (pointers.indexOf(arr) === -1) {
    pointers.push(arr, 0);
  }
  var arrpos = pointers.indexOf(arr);
  var cursor = pointers[arrpos + 1];
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) === '[object Array]') {
    return arr[cursor] || false;
  }
  var ct = 0;
  for (var k in arr) {
    if (ct === cursor) {
      return arr[k];
    }
    ct++;
  }
  // Empty
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand this!